# Dicionário Python

Tags: python, dicionário

O código abaixo deveria fazer a contagem das palavras do texto e no final mostrar a quantidade de vezes que cada palavra aparece no texto.

Estou usando o Spyder (Python 3.7) do anaconda.

```
texto = """Caso tenha o estigma de enfrentar a situação com a mente fria, a situação não se agravara.
 """

def converte_texto(texto):
    pontuacao = ['.',',',':',';','!','?','"','(', ')']
    novo_texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in pontuacao).upper()
    lista = novo_texto.split()
    return lista

print(texto)
print(converte_texto(texto))


def palavras(texto):

    palavras = converte_texto(texto)

    contagem = dict()

    for n in palavras : 
        contagem[n] = contagem.get(n, 0) + 1

        return(contagem)

print( palavras(texto) )
```

No final só mostra o resultado com a primeira palavra, (que ainda por cima não está correto). O certo era fazer contagem mesmo que só com uma palavra.

**Resultado:**

```
['CASO', 'TENHA', 'O', 'ESTIGMA', 'DE', 'ENFRENTAR', 'A', 'SITUAÇÃO', 'COM', 'A', 'MENTE', 'FRIA', 'A', 'SITUAÇÃO', 'NÃO', 'SE', 'AGRAVARA']
{'CASO': 1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é a identação do `return(contagem)`. Você colocou ele dentro do `for`, aí o loop só acontece uma vez e a função retorna. Recue a identação dessa linha que o problema vai ser resolvido. 
Segue abaixo algumas alterações que fiz no seu código:

```
texto = 'Caso tenha o estigma de enfrentar a situação com a mente fria, a situação não se agravara.'

def converte_texto(texto):
    pontuacao = ['.',',',':',';','!','?','"','(', ')']
    novo_texto = ''.join(c for c in texto if c not in pontuacao).upper()
    lista = novo_texto.split()
    return lista

def palavras(texto):
    palavras = converte_texto(texto)
    contagem = dict()

    for palavra in palavras : 
        contagem[palavra] = contagem.get(palavra, 0) + 1

    return contagem

print(palavras(texto))
```

Comment: Muito, obrigado ajudou pra caramba sem querer abusar e como seria adicionar um classificador de palavras que mais tem repetições?? no caso seria um texto grande.

Comment: Se a resposta foi útil e solucionou seu problema, marque como melhor resposta. Não entendi o que você quis dizer com classificador.

Comment: Marquei como a melhor resposta, obrigado, então estou querendo que no final ele classifique as palavras do maior para o menor, (exemplo: 'Situação: 5', 'Mente: 3', 'enfrentar: 2') e assim por diante.